# how to migrate data from MySQL to MongoDB by using pentaho?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, pentaho

I have a three tables in mysql as follows

```
create table document(doc_id int primary key,doc_name varchar(30));
create table tag_info(tag_id int primary key,tag_name varchar(30));
create table maping(d_id int,t_id int,FOREIGN KEY (d_id) REFERENCES document(doc_id),FOREIGN KEY (t_id) REFERENCES tag_info(tag_id))
```

I have inserted some values in three tables.

Combing three tables i want to insert into a mongodb collection ,but i am getting trouble while inserting tags. I want collection as follows

```
 db.m1.find({tag_name:'yy'});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54b4d11631a83e175395da04"), "doc_id" : 11, "doc_name" : "abc", "tag_name" : [ "xx", "yy", "zz" ] }
```